Compile TCL C extension for windows
I successfully compiled my C-extension to TCL using SWIG wrapper, it works in Linux, and compiled successfully under Windows in MSYS64 environment (no errors or warnings),  but when I try to load this module in TCL script, I got this:
this library or a dependent library could not be found in library path

My Makefile is:
all: filter.dll
CC=gcc
BUILD=build

filter.dll: $(BUILD)/filter.o $(BUILD)/filter_wrap.o 
    mkdir -p $(BUILD)
    $(CC) -shared  $(BUILD)/filter.o $(BUILD)/filter_wrap.o $(BUILD)/../tclStubLib.o -o $(BUILD)/filter.dll

$(BUILD)/filter.o: filter.h filter.c
    mkdir -p $(BUILD)
    $(CC) -c filter.c -fPIC -Wall -O3 -g -march=native -o $(BUILD)/filter.o

$(BUILD)/filter_wrap.o: filter_wrap.c filter.h
    mkdir -p $(BUILD)
    $(CC) -c filter_wrap.c -I\C:\msys64\usr\lib\tcl8.6 -fPIC -O3 -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -o $(BUILD)/filter_wrap.o

clean:
rm -rf $(BUILD) filter.dll
Obviously there is some missing libraries but I don't understand which ones. Thank you in advance!

That $(BUILD)/../tclStubLib.o looks suspicious. You ought to use a pre-built tclstub.lib or libtclstub.a as those will use the correct build options...

hello, thank you, I will try that!

Hello!
I replaced it with $(CC) -shared  $(BUILD)/filter.o $(BUILD)/filter_wrap.o $(BUILD)/../libtclstub8.6.a -o $(BUILD)/filter.dll, libtclstub8.6.a is a pre-built library from MSYS distribution. Is it possible to get the name of components that could be missed? The error message doesn't tell this directly

I also doesn't understand why it could not be founded if i provide direct path to this dll

I solved the issue - I select wrong MSYS environment, it should ne MINGW64

If you write that up as an answer, that would be very helpful.

The source of issue was the wrong MSYS environment, it should be MINGW64
